# How to keep contents scrolling under both a navbar and logo image in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a logo image for my site in the upper left, and the navbar right below it. The rest of the contents on my page will scroll under those items, but in the area to the right of my image I can see everything scrolling up... so my question is, is there a way to make that area  above the navbar opaque in some way? So as everything below will scroll under it?

My code right now looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 146px;">    
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div id="top">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span8">
                        <a id="logo" href="/"><img src="img/logo.jpg"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        </br>Some text to the right of logo, above navbar</br>More text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some code, but try putting `background-color: #FFF;` on your `#top` div.